# Powershell - Claims that object property is not empty or null, but Write-Host prints nothing

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, appsettings, ps

I'm very new to Powershell. I'm trying to make a script that can generate local app-settings in JSON using an object containing the properties that I need.

I have a function called "Process-Section" that takes a sectionObject. The section object can either contain individual values, or another section.

If the object contains another section, it should call itself passing the other section as parameter (recursive). If there are no sections in that section it should just call a method called "Process-SingleConfig".

My problem is, that when I reach the maximum depth of my object, you know when there a no more sections and just values, it still claims that the property "sectionObject.sectionName" is not null or empty and therefore it hits the "if block" and tries to call itself with a property that does not exist, but it should in fact go to the "else-block".

You can see the function down below:

```
function Process-Section
{
param
(
    [object]$sectionObject
)

$result = New-Object -TypeName object
Write-Host "SectionObj: $($sectionObject)"
Write-Host "Section Values Count: $($sectionObject.sectionValues.Count)"
Write-Host "Is Section Name in this sectionObject null? $([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($sectionObject.sectionName))"
Write-Host "Is Section Name in this sectionObject empty? $('' -eq $sectionObject.sectionName)"

# Recursive section processing
if(-NOT [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($sectionObject.sectionName)){
    Write-Host "Running through section: $($sectionObject.sectionName)"
    foreach($item in $sectionObject.sectionValues.GetEnumerator()){
        Write-Host $item.localSettingsKey
        Write-Host $item.value
    }
    $nestedSectionObject = Process-Section -sectionObject $sectionObject.sectionValues
    $result |  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $sectionObject.sectionName -Value $nestedSectionObject 

} else {
    Write-Host "Section object that will be processed one config by one"
    Write-Host $sectionObject
    foreach($sectionConfig in $sectionObject)
    {
        $configToAdd = Process-SingleConfig -config $sectionConfig
        $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $configToAdd.key -Value $configToAdd.value
    } 
}

Write-Host "Result $($result)"
return $result;
}
```

On the first run it seems okay

[image]

But then when I can "Process-Section" again with $sectionObject.sectionValues as parameter it SHOULD in fact not have any Name according to the file that I'm testing it on, but it still claims that Name is not null or empty and this is where things get weird.

[image]

Does the new call stack have a reference to the objects from the previous one?

These lines seem to cause the trouble:

```
$nestedSectionObject = Process-Section -sectionObject $sectionObject.sectionValues
$result |  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $sectionObject.sectionName -Value $nestedSectionObject
```

Comment: Try `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Comment: @Theo Now it just completly ignores the if-block, even when its not supposed to

Comment: In the last screenshot it's strange to me that the first line does not show any object yet a count of values shows on the next line for a property of that non-existent object.

Comment: I recommend using a debugger and checking the state of that object on that last run. You can debug in VS Code, Powershell ISE, or directly from the PS prompt

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `if(-NOT [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($sectionObject.sectionName)){` was not the best way to check if the object had a certain property and if it was null. What I had to do instead was use:

```
if($null -ne ($sectionObject | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "sectionName"))
```